# Can I conditionally add a hosted service based on options?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET Core, I can use `IServiceProvider.AddOptions` to register options.

However, I also want to register a hosted service using `IServiceProvider.AddHostedService`, *only if* an option value is `true`.

How can I add a hosted service conditionally, based on options?

Comment: Did you mean `IServiceCollection`? `IServiceProvider` does not have those extensions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your mean correctly , you want to use the option read from other files(such as appsettings.json) to determine whether to add a hosted service .You could refer to the two following different methods:

1.read option value from the appsetting.json in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

```
var option =Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration.GetSection("Options:value").Value);
if(option)
{
   // add hosted services you want
    services.AddHostedService<ServiceName>();
}
```

2.read option value from the appsetting.json in other places

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json"))
               .Build();
var option = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration.GetSection("Options:value").Value);
```

*appsettings.json*

```
"Options":{
  "value": true
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control of how the configuration is set up (it's a library), so I have to rely on getting an `IConfiguration` instance from the DI container, or some other way I have not yet seen an example of.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen can you provide a more detailed example int the post to better explain the situation. It could help in finding potential solutions.

Comment: I'm trying to help the author of this library resolving this issue: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/351

Note the changes made in #390. I want to see if they can be avoided, and make fix the issue in a non-breaking way.